# Drawing conclusions from a characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, characteristic-polynomial

I was given a characteristic polynomial and was asked to draw some conclusions from it, but i need some help with figuring something out. My polynomial is this : $\lambda^4 -3\lambda^3 +\lambda^2 +3\lambda -2$.
I was able to simplify it to this : $(\lambda-1)^2(\lambda+1)(\lambda-2)$. 
So i have 4 eigenvalues $\lambda=1$ (with a 2 degree multiplicity), $\lambda=-1$, $\lambda=2$. The conclusion i have drawn so far is that it can be inverted since the determinant is not $0$. How would i find the rank of the original matrix and how would i answer to whether this matrix could be diagonalizable?

Comment: If the determinant is non-zero its rank is the same as its size, which in turn is the same as the degree of the characteristic polynomial. It need not be diagonalizable since it could happen that the eigenspace associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda=1$ could be of dimension $1$.

Comment: Other stuff you can conclude: (1) If the characteristic polynomial has degree $4$, what is the size of the matrix? (2) Given that the matrix is invertible, what is its rank? As to whether it is diagonalizable or not, you don’t have enough information. Try to give an example of a diagonalizable matrix with that characteristic polynomial, and a non-diagonalizable one with the same characteristic polynomials.

Comment: More stuff you can conclude: exact dimension of *some* of the eigenspaces; upper and lower bounds for the dimensions of the remaining eigenspaces.

Comment: There is something called the minimal polynomial of the matrix. If that has no repeat roots, the matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: @WillJagy: You must also require that it split.

Comment: So my minimal polynomial would be (λ-1)^2(λ+1)(λ-2) or (λ-1)(λ+1)(λ-2)?

Comment: Both can happen. For example, the second is the minimal polynomial of the matrix $\operatorname{diag}(1,1,-1,2)$ and the first of $\operatorname{diag}\left(\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{pmatrix},-1,2\right)$, while both have the first as characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Ok so to make something clear. Without having the original matrix i can't say whether the matrix is diagonalizable or not. Let's assume i have a matrix and i find 3 eigenvalues. Let's also assume that one of these eigenvalues has a multiplicity of 2. i.e  λ=1(2) and λ=3. In order for it to be diagonalizable each eigenvalue needs to have one eigenvector, right? So algebraic multiplicity=geometric multiplicity. If i see that for λ=1 i get 1 vector and for λ=3 i also get one vector it is not diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rank of a matrix is determined by the number of its non-zero singular values (or in the case of square matrices, the number of non-zero eigenvalues). Since the matrix has exactly $4$ non zero eigenvalues, its rank becomes $4$, but nonetheless nothing can be said about its diagonalizability as the following two matrices yield to the same characteristic polynomial$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&2\end{bmatrix}$$
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&-1&0\\0&0&0&2\end{bmatrix}$$while $A$ is diagonalizable and $B$ is not.

Comment: note in your example the matrix $\big(I -A\big)$ and $\big(I -B\big)$ have the same number of non-zero eigenvalues but different ranks, which contradicts your first sentence.